# How To Estimate Website Bandwidth

Tags: web, bandwidth

Having completed several websites in my career, I am familiar with the bandwidth utilization of different websites. However as most of the sits are hosted in either unlimited packages (which implies that its shared amongst others) or 1-2GB monthly bandwidths there isnt any slow site loading times reported as yet.

My question is what is the best way to calculate the bandwidth needed for a typical website (for example, suppose you host the default Joomla page) with an estimated 2000 visitors per day?
Would it be sufficient to simply divide 2000 by the page size? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You should estimate based on: the average pages a user views on your site each day, the average page size, loading failures and retries, etc. loading failures and retrying can be omitted if your server network is fast and your servers has a short responding time. Please be aware that when your bandwidth utilization reaches over 90%, network delay may increases, which will also cause retries.

Comment: Ok, so in that case the results I got from websiteoptimization.com indicate that
Total HTTP Requests: 79
Total Size: 1209802 bytes
As such if I estimate that each visitor would visit 4 pages on average on my site, and I have a 1GB hosting package. Then,
Bandwidth consumed by each user 1209802 x 4 = 4839208
Total Bandwidth allowed 1GB
Maximum no. of monthly visitors = (1024 x 1024 x 1024) / 4839208
                                = 221 users

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: Not sure how your first total size mean - the total size of the home page (as well as the images, etc. )? I do think a page contain 1M data is a bit big. For the same user, the 2nd access to the page may be much smaller, due to the local cache, etc.